# Execute Command Error if it includes spaces

Tags: matlab, server

I have the following command which fails:

```
Execute(h, 'cd C:\Test\My Folder\')
```

However if I remove the spaces (after having to rename the folder) it works:

```
Execute(h, 'cd C:\Test\My_Folder\')
```

Some of my folder paths are quite long at it would be difficult to rename them to remove the spaces. Is there a way around not having to rename the actual folder paths?

Comment: You have to use the escape character for the string identifier `'` (which is a double-single `'`). So in your case: `Execute(h, 'cd ''C:\Test\My_Folder\''')`

Comment: Thanks Hoki, that is perfect. I used " before which did not work but your answer of using ' ' does! thanks!

Comment: How about using the [`cd`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cd.html) command of Matlab?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you have to define a "string containing space" inside a string which will be evaluated.

Example:

In your example, the resulting command that will be executed is the content of your first string, so

```
Execute(h, 'cd C:\Test\My Folder\')
```

would be equivalent to type in the Matlab command windows:

```
>> cd C:\TEMP\My Folder\
Error using cd
Too many input arguments.
```

Which indeed produces an error because the default behaviour for parameters passed in command line without brackets is to split everything after the command at each whitespace character, and send the parameters as string(s) to the command. So in this case, the `cd` command is receiving 2 arguments: `arg1= 'C:\TEMP\My'` and `arg2= 'Folder\'`. The `cd` command cannot deal with 2 input arguments so it errors.

The 2 proper syntaxes would be:

```
cd 'C:\TEMP\My Folder\'                                      %'// ignore that comment
%// OR 
cd('C:\TEMP\My Folder\')
```

Or even with the parameter as a variable:

```
folderPath = 'C:\TEMP\My Folder\' ;                          %'// ignore that comment
cd(folderPath)
```

---

Now your problem is to embed that command (whichever form you choose) into a string. So you will have a `string` within a `string`. In Matlab, the escape character for the string identifier is simply a double `'`. So taking that into consideration, in you case you can use any of the 3 forms given above:

```
execute(h , 'cd ''C:\TEMP\My Folder\''')
%// OR 
execute(h , 'cd(''C:\TEMP\My Folder\'')')
```

or even with parameters:

```
execute(h , 'folderPath = ''C:\TEMP\My Folder\'' ; cd(folderPath)' )
```

Although the last form seems a bit heavy.

---

Finally, if you have to use that many many times, you can use a inline helper function:

```
excmd = @(cmd,arg) execute(h,[cmd '(''' arg ''')'])
```

And then for each of your folder, use the form:

```
excmd( 'cd' , 'C:\TEMP\My Folder\')
```

So you don't need to take care of the single/double `'`, the helper function do that for you (and also this could be a way to use that in a loop, if your folder path were in a cell array for example).